# Alternative to bidimentional array Ruby Programming

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, attributes

The problem is that I need an array of n elements, in which each element has 2 attributes (color and name).
I don't think that using another class and making each element an object would be the best way.

```
class House
    def initialize
        @door=Array.new
        ...
    end
    ...
end

house=House.new
...
puts house.door[i].color
puts house.door[i].name
```

Another alternative is to use a bidimensional array in which:

```
house.door[i][0] would be house.door[i].name
house.door[i][1] would be house.door[1].color
```

But I still think these are not the correct way.

Comment: Is there any question in there or is this rhetorical?

Comment: Why the hesitance to create a new class? If you want to nitpick then every item of an array is an object no matter what you do since there are no primitive non-object types in ruby

Answer (score 2):

If it's a simple script/program, I would use Struct.new(..)

You could have:

```
Door = Struct.new(:name, :color)
door = Door.new("name", "blue")
door.color # => "blue"
door.name  # => "name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a hash:

```
door = Hash.new
door[name] = color
```

Comment: I agree. Basically there are not objects with two properties, but named objects having color. That’s exactly what `Hash` is for. To clarify your point I would improve your naming: `door`⇒`doors`, since there is a whole collection stored in that var.

Answer (score 0):

I would use OpenStruct, saves you from designing a class.

```
house.door[0] = OpenStruct.new(color:'red', name:'Front Door')
house.door[0].color
```

Comment: And how can I do to make the whole array belong to this OpenStruct? I mean, by this way, you have to initialize each element as the OpenStruct.

Comment: You have to manually build them. Since comments sucks and I can't add new lines, here's a gist with that: https://gist.github.com/nhocki/5002120

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think that […] making each element an object would be the best way.

Why do you think that? It's called Object-Oriented Programming and not Array-Oriented Programming for a reason!

Ruby is an object-oriented language. Objects are what it does best.